# Can I play YouTube movies using a custom player (MPMoviePlayerController)?

Tags: iphone, youtube-api, media-player, media

I want to built a custom player and use it to stream YouTube movies.

Is it possible?

Do I need to somehow parse the YouTube link and then pass it to the player?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to get the YouTube streams in any manner that doesn't violate YouTubes terms of service.  I recommend you do two thing to build a custom player.  You can use the chromeless player.  Which will allow you to build a player with minimal YouTube branding and almost no controls.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

You can also use the iframe embed and a couple params.  This way's probably better because you'll get HTML5 and Flash option.  You should set `modestbranding=1` and `controls=0` to get the most minimal chrome and branding.  You can then use the YouTube js api to build your own controls and features.  Here's an example of what the iframe would look like.

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com&modestbranding=1&controls=0"
  frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Use `HCYoutubeParser` by SO member hellozimi to retrieve a usable URL.

https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser